# Shaders for YouTube videos using Three.js in a userscript

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'd like to apply a shader to videos on YouTube.

My current attempt is to use Three.js for that, namely to turn [this example of applying a shader to a video](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=video#webgl_materials_video) (code [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_video.html)) into a Tampermonkey userscript to run on youtube.com.

Are the following `@require` statements correctly translated from [the original `import` statements](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/1a241ef10048770d56e06d6cd6a64c76cc720f95/examples/webgl_materials_video.html#L28-L34)? How do I solve the problems `eslint: no-undef - 'THREE' is not defined`, `eslint: no-undef - 'PerspectiveCamera' is not defined` (if I delete `THREE.`, assuming that the contents of `three.module.js` get imported directly), `eslint: no-undef - 'RenderPass' is not defined`?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=tampermonkey.net
// @grant        none
// @require      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.module.js
// @require      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js
// @require      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass.js
// @require      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/jsm/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js
// @require      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/jsm/postprocessing/BloomPass.js
// @require      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/jsm/shaders/CopyShader.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...

            let container;

            let camera, scene, renderer;

            let video, texture, material, mesh;

            let composer;

            let mouseX = 0;
            let mouseY = 0;

            let windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            let windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            let cube_count;

            const meshes = [],
                materials = [],

                xgrid = 20,
                ygrid = 10;

            const startButton = document.getElementsByClassName( 'title' )[0];
            startButton.addEventListener( 'click', function () {

                init();
                animate();

            } );

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 500;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                light.position.set( 0.5, 1, 1 ).normalize();
                scene.add( light );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                video = document.getElementsByClassName( 'video-stream html5-main-video' )[0];
                video.play();
                video.addEventListener( 'play', function () {

                    this.currentTime = 3;

                } );

                texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( video );

                //

                let i, j, ox, oy, geometry;

                const ux = 1 / xgrid;
                const uy = 1 / ygrid;

                const xsize = 480 / xgrid;
                const ysize = 204 / ygrid;

                const parameters = { color: 0xffffff, map: texture };

                cube_count = 0;

                for ( i = 0; i < xgrid; i ++ ) {

                    for ( j = 0; j < ygrid; j ++ ) {

                        ox = i;
                        oy = j;

                        geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( xsize, ysize, xsize );

                        change_uvs( geometry, ux, uy, ox, oy );

                        materials[ cube_count ] = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( parameters );

                        material = materials[ cube_count ];

                        material.hue = i / xgrid;
                        material.saturation = 1 - j / ygrid;

                        material.color.setHSL( material.hue, material.saturation, 0.5 );

                        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                        mesh.position.x = ( i - xgrid / 2 ) * xsize;
                        mesh.position.y = ( j - ygrid / 2 ) * ysize;
                        mesh.position.z = 0;

                        mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 1;

                        scene.add( mesh );

                        mesh.dx = 0.001 * ( 0.5 - Math.random() );
                        mesh.dy = 0.001 * ( 0.5 - Math.random() );

                        meshes[ cube_count ] = mesh;

                        cube_count += 1;

                    }

                }

                renderer.autoClear = false;

                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove );

                // postprocessing

                const renderModel = new RenderPass( scene, camera );
                const effectBloom = new BloomPass( 1.3 );
                const effectCopy = new ShaderPass( CopyShader );

                composer = new EffectComposer( renderer );

                composer.addPass( renderModel );
                composer.addPass( effectBloom );
                composer.addPass( effectCopy );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                composer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function change_uvs( geometry, unitx, unity, offsetx, offsety ) {

                const uvs = geometry.attributes.uv.array;

                for ( let i = 0; i < uvs.length; i += 2 ) {

                    uvs[ i ] = ( uvs[ i ] + offsetx ) * unitx;
                    uvs[ i + 1 ] = ( uvs[ i + 1 ] + offsety ) * unity;

                }

            }


            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) * 0.3;

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();

            }

            let h, counter = 1;

            function render() {

                const time = Date.now() * 0.00005;

                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;

                camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                for ( let i = 0; i < cube_count; i ++ ) {

                    material = materials[ i ];

                    h = ( 360 * ( material.hue + time ) % 360 ) / 360;
                    material.color.setHSL( h, material.saturation, 0.5 );

                }

                if ( counter % 1000 > 200 ) {

                    for ( let i = 0; i < cube_count; i ++ ) {

                        mesh = meshes[ i ];

                        mesh.rotation.x += 10 * mesh.dx;
                        mesh.rotation.y += 10 * mesh.dy;

                        mesh.position.x -= 150 * mesh.dx;
                        mesh.position.y += 150 * mesh.dy;
                        mesh.position.z += 300 * mesh.dx;

                    }

                }

                if ( counter % 1000 === 0 ) {

                    for ( let i = 0; i < cube_count; i ++ ) {

                        mesh = meshes[ i ];

                        mesh.dx *= - 1;
                        mesh.dy *= - 1;

                    }

                }

                counter ++;

                renderer.clear();
                composer.render();

            }
})();
```

Here's a screenshot of the errors:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eslint: no-undef - 'THREE' is not defined` is not necessarily problematic.

Use [normal JavaScript versions of the Three.js scripts](https://newbedev.com/what-is-the-url-for-three-js-to-include-it-online) instead of module versions:

```
// @require      https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js
// @require      https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js
// @require      https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/RenderPass.js
// @require      https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js
// @require      https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/BloomPass.js
// @require      https://threejs.org/examples/js/shaders/CopyShader.js
```

Add `ConvolutionShader` because `BloomPass` otherwise throws an error saying that it's lacking:

```
// @require      https://threejs.org/examples/js/shaders/ConvolutionShader.js
```

Put `THREE.` before `RenderPass`, `CopyShader`, and so on.

Move `let h, counter = 1;` higher, otherwise `h` is considered as not defined.

Use `container = document.getElementsByClassName( 'video-stream html5-main-video' )[0].parentElement;` because `container = document.createElement( 'div' );` is invisible on YouTube.

Overall, we get the following Tampermonkey userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=tampermonkey.net
// @grant        none
// @require      https://threejs.org/build/three.js
// @require      https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js
// @require      https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/RenderPass.js
// @require      https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js
// @require      https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/BloomPass.js
// @require      https://threejs.org/examples/js/shaders/CopyShader.js

// @require      https://threejs.org/examples/js/shaders/ConvolutionShader.js

// ==/UserScript==
//debugger;

(function() {
    'use strict';
    // Your code here...


            let container;

            let camera, scene, renderer;

            let video, texture, material, mesh;

            let composer;

            let mouseX = 0;
            let mouseY = 0;

            let windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            let windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            let cube_count;

            let hue, counter = 1;

            const meshes = [],
                materials = [],

                xgrid = 20,
                ygrid = 10;


                init();
                animate();


            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                container = document.getElementsByClassName( 'video-stream html5-main-video' )[0].parentElement;
                document.body.appendChild( container );
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 500;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                light.position.set( 0.5, 1, 1 ).normalize();
                scene.add( light );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                video = document.getElementsByClassName( 'video-stream html5-main-video' )[0];
                video.play();
                video.addEventListener( 'play', function () {

                    this.currentTime = 3;

                } );

                texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( video );

                //

                let i, j, ox, oy, geometry;

                const ux = 1 / xgrid;
                const uy = 1 / ygrid;

                const xsize = 480 / xgrid;
                const ysize = 204 / ygrid;

                const parameters = { color: 0xffffff, map: texture };

                cube_count = 0;

                for ( i = 0; i < xgrid; i ++ ) {

                    for ( j = 0; j < ygrid; j ++ ) {

                        ox = i;
                        oy = j;

                        geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( xsize, ysize, xsize );

                        change_uvs( geometry, ux, uy, ox, oy );

                        materials[ cube_count ] = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( parameters );

                        material = materials[ cube_count ];

                        material.hue = i / xgrid;
                        material.saturation = 1 - j / ygrid;

                        material.color.setHSL( material.hue, material.saturation, 0.5 );

                        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                        mesh.position.x = ( i - xgrid / 2 ) * xsize;
                        mesh.position.y = ( j - ygrid / 2 ) * ysize;
                        mesh.position.z = 0;

                        mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 1;

                        scene.add( mesh );

                        mesh.dx = 0.001 * ( 0.5 - Math.random() );
                        mesh.dy = 0.001 * ( 0.5 - Math.random() );

                        meshes[ cube_count ] = mesh;

                        cube_count += 1;

                    }

                }

                renderer.autoClear = false;

                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove );

                // postprocessing

                const renderModel = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera );
                const effectBloom = new THREE.BloomPass( 1.3 );
                const effectCopy = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );

                composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );

                composer.addPass( renderModel );
                composer.addPass( effectBloom );
                composer.addPass( effectCopy );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                composer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function change_uvs( geometry, unitx, unity, offsetx, offsety ) {

                const uvs = geometry.attributes.uv.array;

                for ( let i = 0; i < uvs.length; i += 2 ) {

                    uvs[ i ] = ( uvs[ i ] + offsetx ) * unitx;
                    uvs[ i + 1 ] = ( uvs[ i + 1 ] + offsety ) * unity;

                }

            }


            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) * 0.3;

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();

            }


            function render() {

                const time = Date.now() * 0.00005;

                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;

                camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                for ( let i = 0; i < cube_count; i ++ ) {

                    material = materials[ i ];

                    hue = ( 360 * ( material.hue + time ) % 360 ) / 360;
                    material.color.setHSL( hue, material.saturation, 0.5 );

                }

                if ( counter % 1000 > 200 ) {

                    for ( let i = 0; i < cube_count; i ++ ) {

                        mesh = meshes[ i ];

                        mesh.rotation.x += 10 * mesh.dx;
                        mesh.rotation.y += 10 * mesh.dy;

                        mesh.position.x -= 150 * mesh.dx;
                        mesh.position.y += 150 * mesh.dy;
                        mesh.position.z += 300 * mesh.dx;

                    }

                }

                if ( counter % 1000 === 0 ) {

                    for ( let i = 0; i < cube_count; i ++ ) {

                        mesh = meshes[ i ];

                        mesh.dx *= - 1;
                        mesh.dy *= - 1;

                    }

                }

                counter ++;

                renderer.clear();
                composer.render();

            }

})();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: To suppress these errors add `/* globals var1, var2, ... */` after the userscript metadata.

Comment: @double-beep With `var1, var2` being what for example? `THREE`? Or `h, counter`? I'm not sure which errors you mean.

Comment: This depends on your eslint config. I've set `no-undef` to be an error for example :) You can use `/* globals THREE */`